# Maven internal (local) dependency using it's own properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, maven-plugin

I have a spring project which is being used in a spring boot application as a maven dependency. As that spring project has a lot of things already done in it, i do not want to rewrite whole of the business logic from that. So, what i did is, i maven install it and add as a dependency in my new spring boot app.

Now the issue i am facing right now is that spring project is using variables from properties files (profiles) in many places. After maven install, when i add this dependency in my boot project, i get errors where spring project is unable to get those placeholders (from properties file) in this project.
error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'variable.from.properties.file' in value '${variable.from.properties.file}'
```

So, how we can build the maven dependency with all the variable being inserted in that dependency. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

- Simply put, there are two projects A and B.
- Project A, in one of a class, is using variables from properties file. For instance,
  variable name is, `project.username` and being used in project A as below:

`@Value("${project.username}") private String username;`

- Now i build this project and use
  as a dependency in project B (as normal artifact using dependency tag)
- When i run project B, it complains that
  it cannot resolve placeholder `project.username` because it is not
  anywhere in project B's properties file

`Desire output:`

When i run project B, project A should also pick it's own properties file variables so that i do have to duplicate them in project B.

Hope that is clear.

Comment: Please show the pom file for and which do you define such properties? Please describe the intention of that?

Comment: @khmarbaise i have updated my question. There are no much configurations i want to add here as the issue is straightforward. I want to manage my internal dependency's properties file variable too. Can we do that with maven? Thanks

Comment: Those `@Value` are for spring and should be done via spring boot configuration (application.properties, application.yaml) but not via maven properties...that's simply the issue here...

Comment: but how we can do it in parent dependency?

Comment: I simply don't undestand that. Why do have to do than in the parent dependency? There should be an `application.properties` ? It sounds there are some misunderstandings of using spring components and spring boot concepts??? Maybe my assumption is incorrect?... a more detailed example or even better an example project on github or alike would really help here...

Comment: Never tried to import from another jar but you might want to set `spring.config.import` properties in project B pointing to the property files from project A. Maybe `spring.config.import=classpath:A.jar!app.properties` might work

Comment: @grekier Yes, something like that. Or i just build maven with specific profile and when i add it to project B, on runtime it use the same profile for project A which it was build upon.